# Unable to import statsmodels

Tags: python, python-2.x, statsmodels

I am new to python and I am trying to learn how to use it for statistics. I have been trying to use the

```python
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest
```

But I get an error when I try to use this command.
Here is what it displayed:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 8, in <module>
    from statsmodels.compat.python import lzip, lmap
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/_testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    from statsmodels.compat.pandas import assert_equal
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/pandas.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/jico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/numpy.py", line 46, in <module>
    NP_LT_114 = LooseVersion(np.__version__) < LooseVersion('1.14')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
>>>
```

Any help that I can get would be appreciated. I am using python 2.7.17

Comment: Do you have numpy installed?

Comment: Did you install the package itself as explained on the website ([here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/install.html))? Did you perform a `pip install`?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Do you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also working on python 2.7 facing exactly the same problem.
Here's how I solved it:

First thing first, it says in error message

> NP_LT_114 = LooseVersion(np.**version**) < LooseVersion('1.14')
> Thus make sure you have numpy version > 1.14

Secondly, I downgraded statsmodels from 0.11.0 to 0.10.0.

Hope it works for you too.

(numpy==1.16.5, statsmodels==0.10.0, python=2.7)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue after conda chose to update numpy from 1.13.3 to 1.14.3. Reverting numpy via procedure in http://blog.rtwilson.com/conda-revisions-letting-you-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-your-environment/ sufficed to recover functionality, followed by pinning the version in the environment.

also wondering what does shows:

```
import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)
```